# How give subdirectories for C project to include .h file in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have C project which is divided in Z modules. Each module has its own subfolder which has /inc/ for header files and /src/ for src files. Like shown in image:

[image]

Zth_Module.c has include files from various other modules:

```
/*In Zth_Module.c*/
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"
#include "third.h"
```

If in makefile -I is used, how can path for each subdirectory can be given?
It is showing fatal error: Timer.h: No such file or directory for include file first.h or second.h which are in other subdirectories.

What is the way to provide path to search all *.h files?

Comment: Are you allowed to reorganize your file structure, or to have software libraries (one in each directory)? And please show your actual `Makefile`  in your question! As far as I know  C does not have modules (but C++20 or Ocaml have them). Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Remember that C and C++ are *very different* programming languages.  For C++ read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better. Read also the documentation of your compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: `-I/path/to/inc/of/first -I/path/to/inc/of/second` and so on.. like this it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some approaches to handling this are:

- In the makefile, include a `-I directory` switch in the compilation flags for each directory containing a header file that might be included. The `-I` switch tells the compiler to search the following directory, in addition to the directories it usually searches. For example, you would add switches `-I first/inc -I second/inc -I third/inc` to the compilation flags. You can list the directories manually in the makefile or use GNU Make features for discovering them during the make.
- Add a single `-I directory` switch listing a root directory for the project to the compilation switches and change all the `#include` directives in source code to use paths relative to that root, such as `#include "first/inc/first.h"`.
- Create a makefile target that copies all header files to a single common directory, add one `-I directory` switch for that directory to the compilation switches, and list that target as a dependency for each of the object files, so that make always executes the commands for that target before compiling a source file. That target could be named for the directory used to gather the header files, and it would often be in a temporary or staging area for the build. Also, if you have a `clean` target, one of its actions could be to remove that directory.